# How to manage WildFly/JBoss with multiple Standalone instances

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I want to run multiple webapps in separate standalone instances inside the same WildFly 24 server.
I already created multiple copies of the standalone directory and changed the ports accordingly.
But I do have few questions.

1. In my first standalone I defined a datasource. Unfortunately I can't find it in the other standalone instances. All my apps need this datasource. 
   How can I use jboss-cli to create the datasource in the right standalone instance?
   Or is it possible to define a datasource in a way that is available to all standalone instances?
2. I created custom scripts for each standalone instance to run the right instance with the right config. But how can I use jboss-cli.sh to connect to a specific standalone instance and to be able to restart the instance (`shutdown --restart=true`) ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why are the apps in separate instances?

Comment: Why not? Apps have different goals and different requirements. In separate instances they can run with different VM_opts. If for example one instance run out of memory the other instances are still unaffected.

Comment: Because, as you're indicating, it's harder to manage.  If they are sharing a data source then they are not too different.  I've run Wildfly with dozens of webapps with no problem.  It just seems harder to do for little benefit.  You're correct that memory is still shared but now you have to partition memory on the machine between the various instances rather than one large instance.

Comment: This actually the best practice. This is how Glassfish works. I've been running Payara with 4 domains for many years without problems. Distributing memory between 4 Domains is manageable.

Comment: You might want to have a look at domain mode https://docs.wildfly.org/25/Admin_Guide.html#Domain_Setup. Though there is no reason to not run several applications under one standalone instance.

Comment: I'm aware about the difference btw domain and standalone modes in WildFly. I want to launch multiple standalone instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the right standalone instance, that means you need to specify to which you want to connect to.

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=remote+http://${host}:${instance-management-port}
```

Comment: thanks for you response. What is the local variant for this command? `./jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=${instance-management-port}`. Is there man pages for jboss-cli.sh somewhere?

Comment: Ok, I found the [docu here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Command%20Line%20Interface.html).